# Ionic Capacitor CameraPreview - Camera is always on top. No HTML overlay possible

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, android-camera

I am trying to create a tablet application with a custom camera. I want to achieve a way to have buttons float over de camerapreview. For some reason the camera preview is always on top. I set the isBack to true, but that doesn't make a difference.

My code:

HTML

```
<ion-content [ngClass]="{'custom-ion-content': cameraOn}">
    <div class="cameraOptions" *ngIf="this.cameraOn">
        <button class="center" mat-fab color="primary" (click)="takePhoto()"><mat-icon>add_a_photo</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <ul>
            <li class="slide" *ngFor="let image of this.images">
                <a href="#"><img [src]="image" alt="" /><span>Image Name</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <mat-card class="cameraBackBar" *ngIf="this.cameraOn">
        <mat-icon (click)="stopCamera()">clear</mat-icon>
    </mat-card>
</ion-content>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
// import { CameraPreview } from 'cordova-plugin-camera-preview';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data/data.service';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions, CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewDimensions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-camera',
  templateUrl: './camera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./camera.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CameraComponent implements OnInit {
  cameraOn = false;
  images = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private cameraPreview: CameraPreview) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.cameraOn.subscribe(resp => {
      this.cameraOn = resp as boolean;
      if (this.cameraOn) {
        this.startCamera();
      }
      else {
        this.images = [];
        this.cameraOn = false;
      }
    });
  }
  startCamera() {
    let cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 0,
      y: 64,
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height,
      camera: this.cameraPreview.CAMERA_DIRECTION.BACK,
      tapPhoto: false,
      tapFocus: true,
      previewDrag: false,
      disableExifHeaderStripping: false,
      toBack: true
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts).then(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res)
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err)
        });
    }, 100);
  }

  stopCamera() {
    this.dataService.setCameraState(false);
    this.cameraPreview.stopCamera();
  }

  takePhoto() {
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture({
      width: 1280,
      height: 1280,
      quality: 85
    }).then(image => {
      let picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image;
      this.images.push(picture);
    }, err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.custom-ion-content {
    --background: transparent!important;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cameraOptions {
    height: 64px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: calc(100vh - 64px);
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.cameraBackBar {
    top: -0px;
    height: 64px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 999;
    top: calc(100vh - 214px);
}

.carousel .slide {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I see that the elements are in the right position, only the camerapreview is always on top.
Here are my dependencies that I use.

package.json

```
{
    "name": "kakeswaal-expertise-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Jasbit",
    "homepage": "https://jasbit.nl",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:android-emulator": "ionic build -- -c=androidemulator && npx cap copy android && npx cap open android",
        "build:android-device": "ionic build -- -c=androiddevice && npx cap copy android && npx cap open android",
        "build:android-test": "ionic build -- -c=test && npx cap copy android && npx cap open android"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^10.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
        "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.0",
        "@capacitor/core": "2.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.3.1",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/action-sheet": "^5.29.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^5.30.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.30.0",
        "@ionic-native/device-motion": "^5.30.0",
        "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.29.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.30.0",
        "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.29.0",
        "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^5.30.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.30.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": "^0.12.1",
        "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.1",
        "ionic-cache": "^5.2.0",
        "mat-progress-buttons": "^9.1.1",
        "material": "^0.4.3",
        "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
        "ngx-toastr": "^13.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.5",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
        "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.0",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.5"
    },
    "description": "Kakeswaal expertise app"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your `package.json`, you are using **Cordova Plugin Camera Preview**, which has a known issue of the option `toBack` not working when using it with Capacitor: https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/601

You may want to try the alternative plugin **Capacitor Camera Preview** instead: https://github.com/capacitor-community/camera-preview

Comment: Thank you, I will test this in a later version of the app. I currently added a bar above and under the camera preview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the alpha channel value being set in your CameraPreviewOptions. Make sure to add

`alpha: 1`

in your CameraPreviewOptions. I was facing the exact opposite problem and couldn't see the preview when toBack was set to true while using the Cordova version of the plugin.